# How can I draw on Panel so it does not blink?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, drawing, panel

This is my code. When I move cursor over Form it works, circle is moving but it is blinking. How can I fix this?

```
public partial class Preprocesor : Form
{
    int x, y;
    Graphics g;

    public Preprocesor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Preprocesor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        g = pnlMesh.CreateGraphics();
    }

    private void pnlMesh_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, x, y, 10, 10);
    }

    private void pnlMesh_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;
        pnlMesh.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need to create `Graphics` here? PaintEventArgs already supplied a graphics method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to draw on a double-buffered control.

Make a class that inherits `Control` and sets [`DoubleBuffered = true;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx) in the constructor (this is a protected property).
Use that control instead of your panel it there won't be any flickering.

Also, you should not store a `Graphics` object for later.
Instead, you should draw on `e.Graphics` in the `Paint` handler.

Comment: Thanx. That works :). Except I made control that inherits `Panel`

Comment: @Ichibann: Unless you're also putting controls inside of it, you shouldn't use a panel; it just adds overhead.

Comment: +1 just one small comment - before using this double buffer I used to dispose the `e.Graphics` object every time which didn't cause any problems, but with the double buffer set to true, it caused that nothing was painted. Removed the dispose and all works like a charm..

Comment: @ShadowWizard: You should not dispose an object that belongs to someone else unless the documentation tells you to.

Comment: @SLaks I didn't know that when writing the original code, wasn't sure until you said it, always fearing that behind the scenes it returns new Graphics object that have to be disposed. Maybe due to my SharePoint background - anyway, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It is a new Graphics object, but it's owned and disposed by Windows.

Answer (score 4):

How bout overriding a panel user control and set `Doublebuffered` to true?

```
public partial class BufferPanel : Panel
{
    public BufferPanel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        UpdateStyles();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is `BufferPanel` class but has `TransparentPanel` constructor :P